# Site policies and operation

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, flagging

I have a few questions regarding this site's policies and operation:

1. Is there an administration? Is there a contact for the administration? Is there any entity able to deal with conflicts or disagreements?
2. Why was my question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286991/can-help-fill-the-gap-or-can-help-filling-the-gap closed? I added the information required. I can't understand what is missing.
3. How can I flag user inappropriate comments?

Thanks.

Comment: In re: (1), yes; there are regular users who have been elected by the community to moderate the site: these users are known as "moderators" or "mods" and have a little diamond <> icon at the end of their usernames; in addition to the mods, there are "community managers" who are actual Stack Exchange, Inc. employees who are a sort of super-moderators. They rarely get involved in the day-to-day of individual SE sites. There are 4 ways to contact these people: start a Meta thread, as you've done here, flag stuff, join the chat room, or use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page.

Comment: In re: (3), flagging: simply hover your mouse over the left-hand side of the offensive comment and click the little flag icon. You can choose on of the pre-defined flag reasons (e.g. "spam") or create a custom reason to provide a deeper explanation to the mods.

Comment: @DanBron: you left out the [15-rep requirement](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for flagging.

Comment: @sumelic Oh, I hadn't noticed Joao had 7 rep.

Comment: Joao, John Lawler gave a very good answer to your question...it's in the comments :)

Comment: @michael_timofeev: I interpreted that it only applied to phrases like "I can't help doing that", which he thought about before I gave the complete sentence. Last comment from StoneyB clarifies this doubt of mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Conflicts and disagreements are (usually) initially handled by moderators, and that's initiated through flagging. If you can't flag, then use the [contact us](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link which is at the bottom of every page to contact the Stack Exchange staffers.

   That's also what to do if you don't have the confidence that the moderators are able to deal with your issue.

   Moderators have diamonds in their username (like mine).
2. Your question was closed as "unclear", and required further details. When you edited it, the question entered a review queue where community members with 3000+ rep can vote to re-open if they feel it warrants it.

   However, at 10:48 UTC on 17 November, there was the third "Leave Closed" vote on your question and the system removed it from the queue. While that doesn't mean that it won't be reviewed again, it makes it more difficult to achieve. Your Meta question here might help.
3. If you're not able to flag a comment (it may require 15 rep to do that), then you can get a link from the timestamp and send that to the SE staffer team using the Contact us link.

   You can find if you're able to flag by hovering your mouse over the comment. If it's possible then you will find that a couple of options appear:
   [image: Comment options]
   ...and you can click the flag icon to flag it.

   Moderators *do* deal with comment flags, although the only action which is generally publicly visible is that offensive comments disappear.